# Trim string after and before a character

Tags: php, string

I want to trim this string after "=" and before ";"

```
com=8af14f8b9d5be16e807ab9e0ed1d7edb:b6668c681f9d3bd2ad4ae31a8b6c7f2859939a75;
```

so that it echoes `8af14f8b9d5be16e807ab9e0ed1d7edb:b6668c681f9d3bd2ad4ae31a8b6c7f2859939a75`

Comment: so what have you tried to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `str_replace` function to replace multiple values by, in this case, nothing:

```
str_replace(array('com=', ';'), '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$value="aaaacom=8af14f8b9d5be16e807ab9e0ed1d7edb:b6668c681f9d3bd2ad4ae31a8b6c7f2859939a75;";`
$pos=strpos($value,"=");
echo substr($value,$pos+1,strlen($value)-($pos+2));
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also work:

```
parse_str(trim(
   'com=8af14f8b9d5be16e807ab9e0ed1d7edb:b6668c681f9d3bd2ad4ae31a8b6c7f2859939a75;'
    , ';'));
echo "$com\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```
$str = 'com=8af14f8b9d5be16e807ab9e0ed1d7edb:b6668c681f9d3bd2ad4ae31a8b6c7f2859939a75;';
echo preg_replace('/([a-z]+)=(.*);/', '\2', $str);
```

But it looks like a .ini file, then maybe you want this:

Try this:

```
$ini = 'com=8af14f8b9d5be16e807ab9e0ed1d7edb:b6668c681f9d3bd2ad4ae31a8b6c7f2859939a75;';
$parsed_ini = parse_ini_string($ini);
echo $parsed_ini['com'];
```